# How to replace delimiter of specific column

Tags: text-processing

This is the **abc.txt** file which consist of 5 columns:

```
ID|first name|middle name|last name|address 
1 | john     | whatever  | smith   | somewhere
```

How do I get this output:

```
ID|first name middle name last name|address
1 | john whatever smith            |somewhere
```

How do I replace the `'|'` with space only on specific columns to a new file **def.txt**. In this case, 2nd column until 4th column.

Comment: please post [exact similar your input samples](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385158/how-to-replace-delimiter-of-specific-column#comment685011_385160)

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }{ cs=$2$3$4; gsub(/ +/, " ", cs); print $1,sprintf("%-32s",cs),$5 }' abc.txt
```

- `FS=OFS="|"` - field separator
- `cs=$2$3$4` - concatenated 2nd, 3rd and 4th field
- `gsub(/ +/, " ", cs)` - removing redundant spaces
- `sprintf("%32s",cs)` - formatted concatenated string

---

The output:

```
ID|first namemiddle namelast name  |address 
1 | john whatever smith            | somewhere
```

Comment: It does not have space in between them

Comment: @user6308605, see my update

Comment: Still no space in between them (the combine columns)

Comment: I noticed, using your cmd, it will remove the rest of word containing special character like 'Arrehøj' to 'Arreh'

Comment: @user6308605, what are you talking about? Your input doesn't have special characters. Post screenshots or extend your input to avoid confusing

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -e 's,|\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|,|\1 \2 ,' abc.txt > def.txt
```

[Here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) is a nice introduction that covers the used `s` features.

Comment: if I have more columns to combine, I need to add `|\([^|]*\)` according to how many columns i want to combine?

Comment: Yes, also you need to add `\3 \4` and so on to the right part of the `s` command so the field contents won't get removed altogether with `|` symbols.

Comment: `sed -e 's,|\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|,|\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 ,' abc.txt > def.txt`  does not working. I try to combine 2nd column to 6th column now